# plotting histogram in matlab with highly unequal distribution

Tags: matlab, histogram

So I am plotting two years worth of data to see the change in distribution of values, but with one of the histograms,  one of the years is heavily dependent upon the first column, this is because there are many zeros in the data set. Would you recommend creating a bar strictly for zeros? How would I create this index in matlabd? Or how can I better manipulate the histogram to reflect the actual data set and make it clear that zeros are accounting for the  sharp initial rise?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is very specific to your problem and what you are trying to do, which is impossible to convey in a single paragraph.  It also is not really about programming.  I recommend you boil down your problem to a simple example, along with a description of what you hope to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a statistical question. I f you have good reason to ignore the zeros, for example one of your data aquisition system produced them because of malfunction. you can get simply get rid of them by

```
hist(data(data~=0))
```

but you would not need to look at the histograms anyways you can use the variance or even standard deviation to see how much your data shifted.

Furthermore to compare data populations boxplots are much better and easier to handle.

```
doc boxplot
```

If on the other hand your zeros are genuine to your data you have to keep them! I am sorry but also here the boxplot function might help you because  the zeros might be outliers (shown as little red crosses) or the box is just starting at the zero line.